# Task skipping "Conditional result was False"

Tags: ansible

I`m setting new ansible role to create new IPA users and groups.
User creation works fine, but Im struggling with groups.

This is snippet from my vars and playbook. Ansible version is 2.4.2.0

vars:

```
ipagroups:
  ansible_group_test1:
    group: ansible_group_test1
    users:
    - ansible_test1
    - ansible_test2
  ansible_group_test2:
    group: ansible_group_test2
    users:
    - ansible_test1
    - ansible_test2
  ansible_group_test3:
    group: ansible_group_test3
    users:
    - ansible_test1
    - ansible_test2
```

task:

```
- name: adding ipa groups and  users
  ipa_group:
    name: "{{item.value.group}}"
    state: present
    user: "{{item.value.users}}"
    ipa_host: ipa.example.com
    ipa_user: admin
    ipa_pass: xxx
  with_dict: "{{ ipagroups }}"
  when: item.key == "ipagroups.keys()"
```

I expected the groups to be created, but I get:
 **"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"**

Note: If I try it with e.g. *when: item.key == 'ansible_group_test1'* it works correctly

Comment: Have you tried `when: item.key in ipagroups.keys()`?

Comment: Many thanks!. Works as expected. Anyway, is it somewhere at Ansible pages documented?

Comment: Sort of.  It's actually using jinja2 here, so the place to look is http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators.  Also, you have `ipagroups.keys()` inside quotes, so that is treated as a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `when: item.key in ipagroups.keys()`

I put your vars, *verbatim*, in `group_vars/all`, and have an empty `inventory file`.  This playbook:

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Show vars
    debug:
      var: item.value.group
    when: item.key in ipagroups.keys()
    with_dict: "{{ ipagroups }}"
```

Gives me:

```
TASK [Show vars] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.value.group": "ansible_group_test2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.value.group": "ansible_group_test3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.value.group": "ansible_group_test1"
}
```